# django 2.1 checkboxselectmultiple

Tags: django, python-3.x

Please help.... I am new to django
I keep getting this error on POST method when saving " Select a valid choice. ['DST', 'DAB', 'CGAA'] is not one of the available choices. " here are my codes;

models.py

```
class research_data(models.Model):
      sourcefund_choices = (
        ('DPCIE','DOST-PCIEERD'),
        ('DPCAA','DOST-PCIEERD'),
        ('DST','DOST'),
        ('CHD','CHED'),
        ('DA','DA'),
        ('DAB','DA-BAR'),
        ('CGAA','CSU-GAA(fund 101)'),
        ('C164','CSU(fund 164)'),
        )
      source_fund = models.TextField(blank=True,choices=sourcefund_choices)
      amt_granted = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
      status_res = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=status_choices)
      date_start = models.DateField(blank=True,default=timezone.now)
      date_completed = models.DateField(blank=True,default=timezone.now)
```

forms.py

```
class ktmform_main(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
           fields = {
              'source_fund',
              'amt_granted',
              'status_res',
              'date_start',
              'date_completed',
           }
           widgets = {
              'source_fund': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class':'filled-in','id':'sf'}),
              'amt_granted': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id':'amtg'}),
              'status_res': forms.Select(),
              'date_start': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker','id':'dst'}),
              'date_completed': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'datepicker','id':'dcm'}),
           }
```

views.py

```
def res_add(request):
    if request.method=='GET':
        ktmfrm = forms.ktmform_main()
        args = {
            'ktmfrm':ktmfrm,
        }
        return render(request,'IMS/Res_Form.html',args)
    else:
        ktmfrm = forms.ktmform_main(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if ktmfrm.is_valid():
            ktmfrm.save()
            ktmfrm=ktmform_main()
            args = {
            'ktmfrm':ktmfrm,
            'stat':'saved',
            }
            return render(request,'IMS/Res_Form.html',args)
        else:
            args = {
            'ktmfrm':ktmfrm,
            'stat':'failed',
            }
            return render(request,'IMS/Res_Form.html',args)
```

"source_fund" is the field with CheckboxSelectMultiple as the form widget

Comment: Well, you're using a multiple select widget with a field that only accepts a single value.

Comment: I can't find a suitable model field type for accepting multiple values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an easy way to add a multiple select field

[django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.org/project/django-multiselectfield/)

`from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField`

`source_fund = models.MultiSelectField(choices=sourcefund_choices, blank=True, max_choices='x')`